# Java thread stops with no Exception

Tags: java, multithreading

When I use 4 threads for my program there is usually no problems, but today I increased it to 8 and I noticed 1-3 threads stop working without throwing any exceptions. Is there anyway to find out why they are stopping? is there anyway to make the thread restart?

This is how the structure of my thread is

```
public void run()
{
  Main.logger.info(threadName + ": New Thread started (inside run)");
  while (true)
  {
    try
    {
      //all my code
      //all my code
      //all my code
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Main.logger.error("Exception: " + e);
      try
      {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e1)
      {
        e1.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    finally
    {               
      try
      {
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
        Thread.sleep(3000); 
        Main.logger.info(threadName + ": Closed browser!");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Main.logger.error("Exception: " + e);
      }
    }  
  }// end while
}
```

Regards!

Comment: What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: When you say "stop working" do you mean that the threads terminate, or that they get "stuck" and sit there forever?

Comment: @aroth its hard to say, but when I check the logs the last message is in the finally block, nothing else happens with that thread after the finally block gets executed

Comment: put a console message at the end of the thread's run implementation that says "Peace I'm outta here" or something. Then break on that line or just watch the console

Comment: @nsfyn55 I have many log messages in my thread and when they do end,  it suddenly goes to the finally block and prints threadName: closed browser!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Note that an [`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) is **not** an [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html); it's a [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).
So, if you `catch Exception`, `Errors` will still get through:

```
private void m() {    
    try {
        m(); // recursively calling m() will throw a StackOverflowError
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // this block won't get executed, 
        // because StackOverflowError is not an Exception!
    }
}
```

to catch "everything", change your code to this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Throwable e) {
   // this block will execute when anything "bad" happens
}
```

Note that there might be little you can do if an Error occurs. Excerpt from javadoc for Error:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

Comment: do you know how I can catch it so I can find the reason behind it?

Comment: You catch `Throwable` instead of `Exception`. Note though that recovery is most likely not possible, even simple logging might not work.

Comment: I added a Throwable block and I found out the problem is JVM running out of heap space. After increasing that its working fine :) thanks

Comment: Yeah, no problem. There are so many java programmers out there that don't realise this crucial fact, and like you get stumped when they blow memory of some kind (stack, heap, permgen, whatever). It's one of my favorite interview questions to find out if the "expert" before me is what he says he is :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to find out why they are stopping?

That's a bit tricky.

A Java thread can terminate for two reasons:

- it can return from its `run()` method,
- it can terminate due to an exception being thrown and not caught on the thread's stack.

You can detect the latter case by using an "UncaughtExceptionHandler" for the thread, but the former case can't be positively detected unless you modify your thread's `run()` method to log the event ... or something like that.

I guess, the other way to figure out what is going on would be to attach a debugger to the JVM and get it to report the uncaught exception to you.

(I suspect that the reason you are not seeing any exceptions is that your threads' `run` methods are not catching / logging all exceptions, AND they don't have an uncaught exception handler.)

> is there anyway to make the thread restart?

No. There is no way to restart a Thread that has terminated.

Comment: I just edited my post to include the structure of thread, I've put pretty much everything in try/catch how would I implement UncaughtExceptionHandler in my run method?

Comment: 1) You are not catching Error exceptions. 2) Read the javadocs for java.lang.Thread for the methods for setting an uncaught exception handler.

Comment: true, but you can catch Throwable and instantiate a new look-a-like thread from a template.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running from the command line, you can have dump states of all threads to the console.  On windows you do this by hitting Ctrl+Break, under linux, by sending the QUIT signal to the process with 'kill'.

Please refer to [An Introduction to Java Stack Traces](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/)

> Sending a signal to the Java Virtual Machine On UNIX platforms you can
>   send a signal to a program by using the kill command. This is the quit
>   signal, which is handled by the JVM. For example, on Solaris you can
>   use the command kill -QUIT process_id, where process_id is the process
>   number of your Java program.
>
> Alternatively you can enter the key sequence \ in the window
>   where the Java program was started. Sending this signal instructs a
>   signal handler in the JVM, to recursively print out all the
>   information on the threads and monitors inside the JVM.
>
> To generate a stack trace on Windows 95, or Windows NT platforms,
>   enter the key sequence  in the window where the Java
>   program is running, or click the Close button on the window.

Answer (score 0):

Thread priority on one of them could be too high, try setting them the same level through?
Deadlocking is possible if there is any control on each and other between them.